# Moving file based on date difference using powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell, date, automation

I would like to move files to another location with date difference condition of current month and `LastWriteTime` of file.

I am running below code on `2nd March 2017` and its moving `Dec-16` files but only 1st and 2nd date of `Dec-16` files and there are more then 10 files of `Dec-16` months.

`Jan-17` and `Feb-17` files are not moving which is good. Ideally it should not move `Dec-16` files too as I have written condition as `$Now.AddMonths(-3)`.

That means its checking date as well which I do not want. Code should only check month and move files accordingly. Let date can be anything, If I run the command mid of March month as `$Now.AddMonths(-3)` so file should move till `30th November 2016` and keep `1st Dec-16` till date as it is.

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Lastwrite = $Now.AddMonths(-3)
$childItems = Get-ChildItem $folderNameFull -Include .txt,.xml,.csv,.xls -Recurse | where {$_.LastwriteTime -lt "$Lastwrite"}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your `$Lastwrite` explicitly to midnight of the first day of your target month.

```
$Lastwrite = (Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(-3).Date
$childItems = Get-ChildItem $folderNameFull -Include .txt,.xml,.csv,.xls -Recurse | where {$_.LastwriteTime -lt $Lastwrite}
```